# Twitter bootstrap: button style doesn't work on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

```
                 <nav class="nav-collapse user">
                    <div class="user-info pull-right">
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/35/35" alt="User avatar">
                        <div class="btn-group">                         
                            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                <div><strong>John Pixel</strong>Administrator</div>
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:15px 15px 0 15px;">
                                <form method="POST" style="background:none;">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="<?= lang('username') ?>">
                                    <input type="password" name="username" placeholder="<?= lang('password') ?>">
                                    <input class="btn-default" type="submit" value="Log In">
                                </form>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

Button style doesn't work only on dropdown menu. How I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Log In">

Comment: add class "btn" before "btn-default" like mentioned by Ashish above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class needs to be `btn btn-default`. The base class for all Bootstrap buttons is `btn` and then the secondary class `btn-default` tells it to have the default styling. There is also `btn-primary`, `btn-success`, `btn-info`, `btn-warning`, `btn-danger`, and `btn-link`.

Read more here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

Comment: It may be your theme. Are you including a theme CSS file? Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H8zPG/ It works fine when I include both the CSS and JS from http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/. I also changed the button to `btn-primary` since it's a blue color and is more visible.